# Does it make sense to implement a slab allocator when dealing with small objects?

Tags: c, memory, operating-system

I'm trying to implement a slab allocator for an operating system I'm currently developing. At the moment I think of a design where I have a page that holds a bitmap where I track of allocation status. I want to use it to allocate kernel objects (vfs nodes, scheduler task metadata etc etc). Those structures are from 28 to 48 bytes in size. Would it make sense to use an allocator like that? (my goal is to waste as little memory as possible) If yes, what could be a better way to implement this? (maybe a faster alternative of the bitmap)

```
note before: align rounds to nearest value specified in second argument, pmmPage returns an allocated page
```

EDIT: working code here: https://pastebin.com/xtn1Wg4A